# What is a better way to transform in Scala lift JValue?

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

I am given js1 as a string.
I want to nest "`a`", "`b`", "`c`" under "`abc`".
I feel like this can be done a few lines of code. What is a better way to do this below?

```
val js1 = """
{
    "name" : "test",
    "a" : true,
    "b" : true,
    "c" : true,
    "d" : true,
    "f" : true,
    "g" : true,
    "h" : true,
}
""" 

val jsGroups = parse(js1)

val a = (jsGroups \ "a").values.toString.toBoolean
val b = (jsGroups \ "b").values.toString.toBoolean
val c = (jsGroups \ "c").values.toString.toBoolean
val abc = ("a" -> a) ~ ("b" -> b) ~ ("c" -> c)
val r = jsGroups.remove { x =>
  x match {
    case JField("a", bool) => true
    case JField("b", bool) => true
    case JField("c", bool) => true
    case _ => false
  }

}
val newJs = r.merge(JObject(List(JField("abc", abc))))
println(pretty(render(newJs)))
```

output must be

{
  "name":"test",
  "d":true,
  "f":true,
  "g":true,
  "h":true,
  "abc":{
    "a":true,
    "b":true,
    "c":true
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a `case class`.

```
import net.liftweb.json.{ DefaultFormats, Extraction, JsonParser } 
case class Abc(a: Boolean, b: Boolean, c: Boolean)
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

// to serialize to JValue
val test = Abc(true, true, true)
Extraction.decompose(test)

// to parse from String
JsonParser.parse("""{a: true, b: true, c: true}""").extract[Abc]
```

Comment: I am given the entire js1 as a string tho.

Comment: I have to remove the top level a, b, c too and include d, e, f, g. It can't be just a,b,c